# Controlling the space between <p> elements in a table

Tags: css

Lets say I have a table:

```
"<table border=1>" +
"<tr width=100%>" +
"<th width=50% align='left'><b>Adapted Preliminary Flood Hazard Information</b>" +
"</tr>" +
"<tr width=100%>" +
"<td id='small-lines' width=20%><p>What is <span class='tooltip'>Adapted Preliminary’" + popup1 + "</span> Hazard Information?</p>" +
"<p><span class='tooltip'>What is my property's flood zone’" + popup2 + "</span>   <b>" + graphic.attributes.EFF_FLD_ZN + "</b></p>" +
"<p><span class='tooltip'>What is my property's Post-Storm 1% Elevation’" + popup3 + "</span>    <b>" + graphic.attributes.str_con_LPE + " - " + graphic.attributes.str_con_HPE + "</b></p>" +
"<p><span class='tooltip'>Whats my property's Post-Storm 0.2% Elevation’" + popup4 + "</span>   <b>" + graphic.attributes.str_con_LPE + "</b></p>" +        
"<p><span class='tooltip'>What is my property's observed storm elevation’" + popup5 + "</span>    <b>" + graphic.attributes.str_con_HPE + "</b></p>" +
"<p><span class='tooltip'>Was there erosion on my property based on the event’" + popup6 + "</span>    <b>Yes</b></p>" +
"<p><span class='tooltip'>Is my property within a 30 year erosion risk area’" + popup8 + "</span>    <b>" + graphic.attributes.PARCELID + "</b></p>" +
"<p><span class='tooltip'>Is my property within a 60 year erosion risk area’" + popup9 + "</span>    <b>" + graphic.attributes.PARCELID + "</b></p>" +
"<p><span class='tooltip'>View your property's Storm Event Elevation on our <a href='http://portal.nwfwmdfloodmaps.com/' class='tooltip'>Event Web Viewer." + popup10 + "</a></p>" +
"<p>Where can I get <a href='http://portal.nwfwmdfloodmaps.com/' class='tooltip'>GIS Data" + popup11 + "</a> for my property area’</p>" +
"<p></p>" +
"</td > " +
"</tr>" +
"</table>"
```

The table looks like this:

[image]

Lets say I want to control the amount of space between each `<p>`. Maybe I want to make them tighter together. I assume I need some CSS but I am not sure how to correctly apply it to tighten the space between the default line breaks in my `<p>` paragraphs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
p { margin:0 }
```

This will make them tighten

What is CSS Margin? [Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `p { margin: 5px 0; }` where 5px is whatever you actually want the space between paragraphs to be. (First number specifies top/bottom margins, the second specifies left/right margins.)